# Ajax custom function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to build a custom function for ajax but the output is "null"

```
$("form[id*='admin-handler/announcements'] #submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ajaxCall("/admin-handler/announcements", $(this).serialize(),  function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });

});
function ajaxCall(_url, _data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _url,
        data: _data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

so.. what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You should check in your developer tools, under `Network`, what you receive from your server first.

Comment: What appens when you go to /admin-handler/announcements manually in a browser?  I assume that is returning you a JSON string and all working OK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(this).serialize()` in your argument list will try to serialize `#submit`, not the `form` element to which it belongs.

And since you're accessing `#submit` via its ID, the preceding `form` selector *should* be redundant.